# How to use a batch size bigger than one in Bert Sequence Classification?

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis, huggingface-tokenizers

[Hugging Face documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertforsequenceclassification) describes how to do a sequence classification using a Bert model.

Code I am using for a CSV dataset:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import BertTokenizer, TFBertModel

def get_embeddings(model_name,tokenizer,name,inp):
    tokenizer = tokenizer.from_pretrained(name)
    model = model_name.from_pretrained(name)
    input_ids = tf.constant(tokenizer.encode(inp))[None,:]  # Batch size 1
    outputs = model(input_ids)
    last_hidden_states = outputs[0]
    cls_token=last_hidden_states[0]
    return cls_token
cls_token=get_embeddings(TFBertModel,BertTokenizer,'bert-base-uncased',z[0])
cls_token
```

There is only example for batch size 1. How to implement it for 48k entries and form an appropriately-sized Tensor afterwards?